# Does the fingerprint reader in Vostro 1320 work in Windows 7?

Tags: laptop, compatibility, fingerprint, dell-vostro

I don't want to hear Dell's official stand on this.

Anybody got it to work in Windows 7 in the real world? Dell told me it's unsupported, but unsupported in tech support speak really means : "if you want it to work you're on your own buddy."

Fine, I'm a power user, I can deal with that. But Dell refuses even to sell me the Vostro 1320 with the biometric hardware when Windows 7 is bundled. They'll only sell me if I can prove to them it works.

So, anybody that has got their 1320's biometric stuff workng in Win7, I'll appreciate it if you can help me out and post a screenshot or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fingerprint reader in Vostro 1320 has a Vista driver, then that same driver has a really excellent chance to work in Windows 7.

If Dell requires a proof, you might point them at :

[Blog of Grant George, VP of Test for the Windows Experience](http://blogs.msdn.com/e7/archive/2009/03/03/application-compatibility-testing-for-windows-7.aspx)

> Our main Application Compatibility
>   goal for Windows 7 is to make sure
>   that most all applications which work
>   on Windows Vista will continue to work
>   seamlessly on Windows 7.

[Windows 7 Drivers Must Be Vista-Certified](http://www.driverdetective.org/driver-detective/windows-7-drivers-must-be-vista-certified/)

> Microsoft announced on June 1 that all
>   hardware manufacturers seeking
>   certification for Windows Vista must
>   also test their drivers on Windows 7.
>   According to documentation on
>   Microsoft’s Web site, “…all Windows
>   Vista client and Windows Server 2008
>   submissions must include a complete
>   test log for the new beta OS.”

[Windows 7 will support all Vista-certified drivers](http://www.pctipsbox.com/windows-7-will-support-all-vista-certified-drivers/)

> Compatibility with devices designed
>   for Vista ensures that users will have
>   a seamless upgrade/migration
>   experience. Grant George, the VP of
>   Test for the Windows Experience,
>   revealed that Microsoft had full
>   compatibility with Vista-certified
>   drivers for Windows 7 as a primary
>   goal.

[The Windows 7 Ballet with Drivers and Compatibility](http://news.softpedia.com/news/The-Windows-7-Ballet-with-Drivers-and-Compatibility-102076.shtml)

> While building Windows 7, Microsoft is
>   attempting to resolve scenarios that
>   managed to successfully handicap
>   Windows Vista in terms of
>   compatibility. In this context, in
>   order not to break devices that
>   currently work with its precursor,
>   Windows 7 will come to the table, from
>   the get-go, with support for all
>   Vista-certified drivers. Compatibility
>   with devices designed for Vista
>   ensures that users will have a
>   seamless upgrade/migration experience.
>   Grant George, the VP of Test for the
>   Windows Experience, revealed that
>   Microsoft had full compatibility with
>   Vista-certified drivers for Windows 7
>   as a primary goal.

Answer (score 0):

I only have a Latitude XT2 here and didn't bother to install the finger print reader's drivers but they exist. I just don't need it and didn't want a 60 MiB download back then.

So *iff* the hardware in question is the same, then it should work with Win 7 (assuming existing drivers are in fact a guarantee of "working"). The hardware IDs are

```
USB\VID_0A5C&PID_5801&REV_0102
USB\VID_0A5C&PID_5801
```